# VWhat is the visibility of statics declared inside a member function in C++?

Tags: c++, static

So I understand that:

```
class Foo {
    public:
    static int bar;
}
```

Means I can access `Foo::bar` more or less anywhere.

But what about code like this?

```
class Foo {
    public:
    static int* bar() {
        static int fred = 1;
        static int barney = 2;
        static int thelma = 3;
        return &thelma;
   }
};
```

How do I access `fred` and `barney`? I understand they are created only once and they exist for the lifetime of the program but presumably they aren't accessible as `Foo::barney`.

I have seen this pattern in real code and so wondering how it works.

Comment: They are only accessible locally from within the bar() function, just like any other local variable. The big difference is that they are initialized onze and persist over multiple calls to bar()

Comment: Thanks - well that's the simplest and most obvious answer but I wondered if I was missing something. But what happens if multiple Foos are created?

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin What happens such as what? Nothing changes. There is no reason for the behaviour to change: instances are irrelevant to `static`. A variable is only visible within the scope it is declared in.

Comment: Well lets say the variables were initialized to the time of day - what value will they have - the same over all instances of Foo (as they would if they were static members) or different - as they would if they were autos?

Comment: They are static. They don't change with instances. That's what `static` means.

Comment: `bar()` is static - so you don't use any instance to call it. If `bar()` wasn't static, all instances of `Foo` would access the same `fred` etc. variables when calling `bar()`.

Comment: Thanks @Yksisarvinen - that answers my point

Comment: So in other words whether `bar()` is static or not makes no difference. Hard to see why you introduced this complication. @adrianmcmenamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important concept in C++: [visibility](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) and [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) of variables.

> How do I access fred and barney? I understand they are created only once and they exist for the lifetime of the program but presumably they aren't accessible as Foo::barney.

You can't access them (not at least via their name as compiler won't be able to link them as they have no-linkage). Static variables inside your member function has *visibility* only inside the function; *lifetime* of the program (to be precise, it begins the first time the program flow encounters the declaration and it ends at program termination) and [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage).

`static` variable are used in singleton design pattern. Since, they have limited visibility but program's lifetime, that's how you can access a static variable outside the member function.

```
class A {
public:
    A& getInstance()
    {
        static A self;
        return self;
    }

     A(const A&) = delete;
     A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
private:
    A();
};
```